# Is there any way to create multilingual dashboard with Grafana?

Tags: grafana, dashboard

I would like to set the same dashboard on different langues. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: i18n is currently not supported in grafana.

Comment: Thanks for your message. I suppose that I have to create a dashboard for each langue.